# python mysql printing not null values

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I want CASE to overlook `NULL` values in `students TABLE`.

```
dict = db.execute("""SELECT first, middle, last, birth FROM students WHERE house = (%s)
CASE ISNULL(middle, 'NULLVALUE') 
WHEN 'NULLVALUE' THEN '' 
ELSE '[middle]'
END
GROUP BY first ORDER BY last;""", house)
```

It returns:

> RuntimeError: near "CASE": syntax error
> and interpreter points to line:

```
GROUP BY first ORDER BY last;""", house)
```

I want it to output something like: `if middle IS NULL: print(dict[i]["middle"]) as '', else: value`

Though without the case lines, it works as it should:

```
print(#line) 
Harvey None Spectrum, born 1980
```

Comment: what is the need of group by here ?

Comment: This use of `NULLVALUE` as a string is just asking for trouble. Why are you doing that? You also don't need to do `house = (%s)` you can just do `house = %s`.

Comment: It's not clear what's going on here. Are you trying to compare the `house` column to the middle name?

Comment: Don't use CASE. You should use COALESCE(middle,'')

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid  it sorts members alphabetically by their first name, if they have the same last name

Comment: @tadman am trying to print out everyone on the list without the None value python prints out when somebody doesn't have a middle name

Comment: I solved the problem by tweaking the python code, checking if middle name is NoneValue, ignoring sql CASE statement altogether.

Comment: Do the formatting in Python by identifying `None` results and skipping them in display. Don't fight it in MySQL. You'll only end up making a mess of things, and getting results like `First  Last` with two spaces.

Comment: @tadman right; is what I did

Comment: The alternative is `IFNULL(middle, '')` which will default it to an empty string, but that creates other problems. This is a presentation problem, not a database problem, so it's something you should take care of in Python. Test if there's a middle name, if not, format accordingly. You should have some kind of name to string presenter that can deal with any of these elements missing.

Comment: @tadman I have had problems with the IFNULL() function, yielding errors in the interpreter. Python actually stores the db.execute command as a dictionary, so names are printed whether the key is empty or not

Comment: Don't leave us hanging, what errors did you get? Can you post the specific error and the query that generated it? It's better to do this by editing your question an amending it with more details, code in comments is often unreadable.

Comment: @tadman I have already submitted the problem; the online IDE I am using was very vague, it only said 'Error Near IFNULL(middle, '')' or 'Error Near CASE'

Comment: That's not vague, that indicates precisely where the problem is, but that doesn't match what you're showing here.